# Managing Read and Unread messages with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a chat application with php and mysql. Where users can send messages to each other.

Now I want to implement a "read" and "unread" messages system.

Forexample Title of A unread message should look "black" and Title of a read message "Gray".

My table structure :

```
MessageId SentTo SentBy Created Status
```

Status column is for message status (Read|Unread) by default Unread.

I have a **readmsg.php** file When a user clicks on Message title in Inbox.php he is redirected to **readmsg.php** and there he can read the full msg.  there also an Insert Into statement runs, this updates the **Status** column with **Read** .

**Readmsg.php**

```
 $mid=$_GET["msgid"];
 $you=$_COOKIE['username'];
 $st= "SELECT*FROM msgbox WHERE sentto='$you' AND id='$mid' LIMIT 1";


 #Script to update Status column
```

This all works  but It's really very hard to manage .

Is there an easy way to manage read and unread messages with php and mysql?

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: I do not understand the problem... Why do you use a new insert statement? You can simply update...

Comment: What is hard to manage about updating (not inserting) a field upon read?

Comment: Richard sorry my mistake, it's update statement.

Comment: I would suggest the `id` column in `msgbox` be an autoincrement integer. It would require less management. You would use ->insert_id to get the auto generated id after the insert. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)